# What is the regex for anything.com/anypage.html to redirect to anything.com/anypage

Tags: regex, .htaccess

In my htaccess file I would like to get the right regex for matching the following

anything.com/anypage.html would redirect to anything.com/anypage

So this would basically allow the html to get stripped off my urls.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```